# Kelp balanced strategy amount confusion

Tags: kelp

I'm setting up a Kelp **balanced strategy** on StellarX, and so far I got it working and trading, but I'm very confused about the amounts that Kelp bids. It only seems to bid **small amounts**, fractions of XLM. My Account has ample funds, and I've even tried filling half the account with the other token, but I can't get the amounts that are bid any larger.

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? Which variables of the Balanced strategy govern this, if at all?

Answer (score 0):

Kelp is pretty opaque.  I cannot find any documentation that describes how the bot processes the balanced strategy config files in the pricing and amounts of bids and offers.  I cannot tell what's going on in the bot's "mind".

Answer (score 0):

In the balanced strategy, the target amount of the bid uses the following formula:

```
targetAmount = (2 * availableAmount * spread) / (4 + spread)
```

and then reduce it by 5%. If you have multiple bid levels, then the `availableAmount` changes with increasing levels and the `targetAmount` decreases. The `targetAmount` for the balanced strategy cannot be controlled by any other configuration variable except the `spread`. But, if you increase the spread, then your `targetPrice` will also change.

For more details, see the code [here](https://github.com/stellar/kelp/blob/8404d16748984e9212aabc2911615e0a89cb364c/plugins/balancedLevelProvider.go#L190).

As far as my understanding: If you want to control the order size, then you have to use the pendulum strategy. In balanced strategy, the mid market rate is obtained as `assetA / assetB`. So, a larger bid size will shift the balance leading to unrealistic bids and asks.

Edit: I downloaded the source code and modified the balanced strategy to include a configuration flag `AMOUNT_MULTIPLIER` to control the amount that Kelp bids. This is **not** suggested as it may lead to unrealistic bids and asks -- leading to significant losses in the market.